# Prolog: How to create a program that doesn't allow for a number to be neighbour to another number

Tags: prolog, between

I want to write a prolog program that needs a number to stay between 2 other numbers but to not have a specific number as his neighbour.

For exemple i have the numbers 1,2,3,4,5. I want for number 5 to stay between any other number except 4.

How can i do that?

Comment: You need to add more information. How does the predicate should look like? In the example you give `1,2,3,4,5` - should this be a list? Or just an interval?

Comment: It should be a list. I know that in other programs like C you need to use loop, but how can i a think like loop in prolog?

Comment: Before thinking about loops, think about how you would use it! Give an example for that first.

Comment: I was thinking if 'L4 = 4' and 'L5 = 5' then in prolog i would make something like 'L4 is L5 - 1 ; L4 is L5 + 1'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem is if 'L4 = 4' and 'L5 = 5' then in prolog i would make something like `'L4 is L5 - 2 ; L4 is L5 + 2' where L5 not(L5 = 1 ; L5 = 5)`. Then the compiler will show something like `1,4,2,5,3`.